# how to mock model->save()?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I need to mock a db model that calls the function save().

**Test**

```
//Setup function  
$this->jobAccessor      = Mockery::mock(JobAccessor::class);
$this->job              = Mockery::mock(Job::class);
$this->app->instance('App\Models\Job',          $this->job);
$this->app->instance('App\Data\JobAccessor',    $this->jobAccessor);


//testing function
$job = new Job([
        'id'            => 22,
        'user_id'       => 123
    ]);

$this->jobAccessor->shouldReceive('find')
   ->with($jobId)
   ->andReturns($job);

$this->job->shouldReceive('save')->once();
```

**function to test**

```
 $job = $this->jobAccessor->find($this->id);

 //do stuff with job then save

 $job->save(); //how do I mock save here?
```

How can i mock `$job->save();` the way i done above doesnt work. I get the following errors `Illuminate\Database\QueryException: could not find driver`. It's trying to access the database still.

Comment: You don't mock that method, you don't mock any core classes/methods except Facades... Why do you want to mock that method ? If you expand on that, I can help you create a good test, but you don't have to mock that method never.

Comment: @matiaslauriti why not if you dont want it to talk to the Db how would you do it?

Comment: That is the issue, you talk to the DB or you test another way but never mocking core classes like `Model`. Can you explain (edit your question) exactly what you want to test ? Show the code and dependencies, and I will add an answer explaining and showing you how to accomplish that (the right way).

Comment: @matiaslauriti i dont know if i can add anything else to explain what im doing.
I basically need to test a function (you can see it in the ``function to test`` section) however when trying to test that function, I get error because the ``$job->save()`` is trying to connect to the database. I dont want to talk to the db, so how could I test that function?

Comment: @matiaslauriti I dont want to add anything more from the actual code just for security reasons.

Comment: you have to add a "mock" database, you could try switching to SQLite, that would be `DB_DATABASE=:memory:` and `DB_CONNECTION=sqlite`, so that would be local.

Comment: @matiaslauriti ahh so instead of mocking ``Model`` class, i mock the database? do you have any example please?

Comment: Yes, `mocking the database` it is not a good phrase, because you are not mocking it, you are just using another one (empty) so you can do whatever you want with that data and don't risk any real data. Just have a look at the official [`phpunit.xml`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/4f8a0f35fabd8603fb756122bf820719a259ac9b/phpunit.xml#L24-L25), those lines are commented, if you turn them on, you will have a database in memory, but you can also create a new database in MySQL or whatever you use, just use another database.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but I think you need to declare the save method as :

```
$this->job->shouldReceive('save')->with(m::on(function ($job) use ($data) {
    // set all attributes of your job Model
    return 
        $job->id == $data['id']
        && $job->name == $data['name'];
        // ....
}))
  ->andReturns($this->job)
  ->once();
```

Comment: Also the job accessor should be `->andReturns($this->job);`

Comment: @apokryfos it return $job because if you in the code i provide. I need to implement a job model with values as it is used through the code. If i return $this->job the code will fail because the job model is empty. there are several place that the $job is accessed.

Comment: @Luke Create a [partial mock](https://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/partial_mocks.html) that is mostly real but can mock calls like e.g. `save`

Comment: Okay thanks i will look at partial mock, that might be what i want. Also what is ``m:on`` I get ```Error: Class 'm' not found``` @Vincent

Comment: For anyone reading this, you don't mock core classes/methods in Laravel. You only mock Facades. The author is testing wrongly. He must expand why he wants to do that, as there is a better solution.